# O PHP é considerado open source?

Tags: php

O PHP é considerado de código aberto? Se sim, há repositórios tal como o Chromium onde podemos ver suas "entranhas" e/ou colaborar para seu desenvolvimento?
Se não for, ela deve algum direito às linguagens CGI, C, C++? Já que foram estas utilizadas para sua criação até os dias atuais.

Fiz algumas pesquisas mas só encontro respostas vagas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim ele é open-source, mas esta licenciado sob uma licença própria deles `The PHP License, version 3.01`, o que implica em várias questões que **podem** ser "legais", incluindo o uso do nome "PHP", não posso comentar mais sobre essas questões "legais" pois não domino o assunto e elas não pertence ao tópico/escopo do site.

Você pode contribuir para melhorar o PHP seguindo isto:

- https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

E pode baixar os GITs específicos através dos endereços citados em:

- http://git.php.net

O PHP (interpretador) é divido em várias partes para o desenvolvimento sendo a principal este `git@git.php.net:/php-src.git`.

A maior parte do PHP é escrito em [c](/questions/tagged/c), é necessário entender que isto é o "interpretador", ou seja é um programa que interpreta scripts escritos em PHP, assim como muitas linguagens de programação são interpretadas, elas dependem de um programa que as interpretem.

---

### Extra

Um exemplo de "fork" do PHP é HHVM (HipHop Virtual Machine), que é uma *máquina virtual* (semelhante a máquina virtual Java, que executa softwares escritos na linguagem Java e ambos usam Jit - compilação just-in-time), no entanto o HHVM não é bem uma fork, ele é quase que um interpretador PHP reescrito para que suporte a linguagem propria deles chamada `hack`, que é semelhante a linguagem PHP e que também tenha compatibilidade com PHP.

---

### Extra 2:

Só pra constar CGI não é linguagem de programação, é uma **"porta"** que permite executar interpretadores ou programas via servidores HTTP, isto deve ser um dos motivos de confundirem Perl com CGI, lembro que ouvia algumas pessoas falarem que programam em "cgi" quando na verdade programavam em Perl.

É possível criar até um programa **compilado** que trabalhe com HTTP e configurar para que ele rode com CGI, claro que hoje o mais comum é usar Fast-CGI, justamente devido a questões de performance.

Comment: Mas me diga, o PHP deve direitos às suas linguagens base?

Comment: O que eu fico na duvida é isso: a pergunta é fora do escopo a resposta é excelente e responde a pergunta que é fora do escopo do site, porque a pergunta fica levando votos negativos e a resposta positivos, nada contra a ninguém, mas, uma observação de comportamento.

Comment: @thiago o que e linguagem base? PHP é o interpretador de script PHP. Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic tentei promover a parte que creio que cabe ser programação, que é o desenvolvimento e modificação do interpretador de scripts PHP. Creio que é o tipo de pergunta que fica na linha limite do on-topic/off-topic.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento me refiro às linguagens que deram origem ao PHP, lá nos anos de 1994 com Rasmus Lerdorf e até as utilizadas atualmente, como C, C++.

Comment: Essas linguagens não deram origem ao php @thiago, o Rasmus se inspirou em aspectos do C e do Perl para criar o PHP. Só pra constar, CGI não é linguagem, é apenas um "porta" no servidor para executar programas através de interpretados configurados, como o interpretador do Perl ou o interpretador do PHP.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendi, agradeço os esclarecimentos! Mas jurava que CGI era uma linguagem, pois comecei a programar pelo CGI/Perl.

Comment: @thiago usar a porta CGI é algo meio arcaico, hoje existe o Fast-CGI, o qual você pode desenvolver um programa que funcione com proxy-reverso, ou procurar conhecer linguagens como Python (que ao invés de cgi pode-se usar o WSGI, que é um CGI propriamente feito para Python), se quiser escrever scripts PHP os servidores usam o modulo proprio do Apache (geralmente) ou fast-cgi, o que dispensa outras configurações. Se quer programar web recomendo pessoalmente que procure linguagens e ferramentas "mais" voltadas para isto.

Comment: Entendi, valeu @GuilhermeNascimento